# Calculate mean of arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Given three lists:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = [7, 8, 9]
```

How do I calculate the mean of the following (the columns)?

- Mean of [1, 4, 7]
- Mean of [2, 5, 8]
- Mean of [3, 6, 9]

Not the following (the rows),

- Mean of [1, 2, 3]
- Mean of [4, 5, 6]
- Mean of [7, 8, 9]

---

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([4,5,6])
C = np.array([7,8,9])
```

What should I do?

Comment: It's clearly written in the docs : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

Comment: this question is not just about calculating mean but before that lists have to be arranged, but how?@ Raiyan

Comment: This question should not be closed as off-topic, but a duplicate probably exists (given it is so basic (or others have posted the same home work-like question)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [numpy.ndarray.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.array([
...     [1,2,3],
...     [4,5,6],
...     [7,8,9]
... ]).transpose().mean(axis=1)
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
```

or using [numpy.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.transpose([
...     [1,2,3],
...     [4,5,6],
...     [7,8,9]
... ]).mean(axis=1)
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
```

**UPDATE**

As Dave Hirschfeld commented, mean over `axis=0` is alot better:

```
>>> np.array([
...     [1,2,3],
...     [4,5,6],
...     [7,8,9]
... ]).mean(axis=0)
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
```

Comment: Even though a transpose in numpy simply returns a different "view" on the underlying data and doesn't actually copy or move any data it still seems a bit redundant - just take the mean over `axis=0`

Comment: @DaveHirschfeld, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to your comment. Sorry for responding too late.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([4,5,6])
C = np.array([7,8,9])

Z = zip(A,B,C)

for z in Z :
    print np.mean(np.asarray(z))
```